# c++ problem inorder printing binary tree recursively

Tags: c++, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I have been practicing some old C++ problems to prepare for a few job interviews, and I am currently trying to recursively construct a binary tree from an array, and then print it inorder recursively as well. However, I got some weird values when trying to output the result.

Problem : construct binary tree from array [4,2,5,1,3], and then create a function that prints
          them inorder recursively.

Answer : I am able to print the result, however my solution contains some unexpected 0's that also gets printed within the result. I dont have a clue how those 0's can end up being in the printed results..

Here is the printed result I currently have (notice the unwanted 0's between values) :
                      `0 1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0`

Here is the c++ solution I have written. (Just copy and paste and run it on your compiler):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 5;

struct node{
    node *leftBranch;
    node *rightBranch;
    int val;
};

int data[SIZE] = {4,2,5,1,3};
node* construct_tree(int);
void print_tree(node*);

node * construct_tree(int num){
    node *tmp = new node();
    if(num < SIZE){
        tmp->leftBranch = construct_tree(2*num + 1);
        tmp->val = data[num];
        tmp->rightBranch = construct_tree(2*num + 2);
    }
    return tmp;
}

int main(){
    node *tree = construct_tree(0);
    print_tree(tree);
    return 0;
}

void print_tree(node* tree){
    if(tree == NULL)
        return;
    print_tree(tree->leftBranch);
    cout<<tree->val<<" ";
    print_tree(tree->rightBranch);
}
```

I think I have been a little rusty with c++ and recursion..I hope you guys can help me.thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in construct_tree. The calls to it are:

```
construct_tree(0) -- from main()
    construct_tree(1)
        construct_tree(3)
            construct_tree(7)
            construct_tree(8)
        construct_tree(4)
            construct_tree(9)
            construct_tree(10)
    construct_tree(2)
        construct_tree(5)
        construct_tree(6)
```

The problem is, *every call* to construct_tree creates a new node that is added to your tree, even when `num` is out of range.

Comment: In other words, if we consider that `construct_tree` should fail whenever `num >= SIZE`, we will be amazed to find out that the current code will still allocate the `new node()`, return it to the caller, and the caller will assign it to `tmp->leftBranch` or `tmp->rightBranch` (effectively adding a child which has not been initialized). To fix the bug, `construct_tree` will need a way to signal a failure condition to its caller.

Comment: It could just return `null`. Then the parent node will have `null` in the correct child slot.

Comment: and @rwong : thanks for the quick responses. you guys made good points :)

Answer (score 2):

Ted is right. Try changing construct_tree as follows :- 


`node *tmp = null;

if(num < SIZE)

{

     tmp= new node();

     ......

}

return tmp;`

Answer (score 1):

You have another problem. Your algorithm for ordering the tree is highly dependent on the order in which you visit the data. Try your solution on

```
int data[SIZE] = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
```

Comment: I don't think so. In OP's code, the content of each node and its two children are determined by `num`, `2*num+1` and `2*num+2` respectively, i.e. not by the order of node creation. (This arrangement results in a [binary heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap).)

Comment: @rwong Actually I think @djna is correct in his assumption. You are right `2*num+1` and `2*num+2` are passed as parameters to the recursice `construct_tree()` calls, but their value is used as an index for accessing the data array. So the order of the data in the array determines the structure of the tree, not their actual values.

Comment: In OP's "interview question", the values in the array are probably chosen by the interviewer such that when the tree is constructed in the style of a binary heap, the in-order traversal of that tree would result in `1 2 3 4 5`. (The OP didn't mention what specification the interviewer has on the tree's construction, though.)

Comment: I agree with you. In your case, 2 will be the root node, the subsequent left subtree will contain 4(root), 5(left), 3(right), and right subtree will contain 1. I think a way to get around that is to build a tree-insertion function that compares the value of new element to the current root before doing the insertion..@rwong: I actually chose the value to be that way myself so that it would be printed  1 2 3 4 5 inorder :)